# How would I factor, and find this derivative?

Tags: derivatives

I'm not really confused on finding the derivative I'm confused when it asks me to factor. How would I solve this? 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after the quotient rule we obtain: $$f'(x)=\frac{4(3x-2)^3\cdot 3(2x+5)^8-(3x-2)^4\cdot 8(2x+5)^7\cdot2}{(2x+5)^{16}}$$
is this clear?
and now we factorize:
$$f'(x)=\frac{(3x-2)^3(2x+5)^7\left(12(2x+5)-16(3x-2)\right)}{(2x+5)^{16}}$$
can you finish?

Comment: Yes! Up to here it makes sense.

Comment: How did you get 12 to be attached to (2x+5)?

Comment: the $4$ from the exponent and the $3$ from the chain rule

Comment: Wouldn't it be -16(3x-2) * 12(2x+5) ? to show that theres something being factored on the right hand side?

Comment: but you can find the answer of all your questions above get a pencil and calculate

Comment: oh sorry! The answer was correct. I'm just trying to understand the factoring, and how you formatted it.

Comment: you are welcome